# Use Theme CSS in custom code

Tags: customization, css

I'm busy creating a page with Divi, which contains various forms, that will be used for calculations.

Is it possible to use the same css stylesheet as the theme? This will ensure that custom code is also aesthetically pleasing.

It is easy to find posts that explain how to use custom css on pages and the theme but none the other way around.

Comment: By default the theme should apply it's standard CSS rules to all the elements loaded onto a page.  The DIVI theme's stylesheet should (assuming it was made properly) have general styling rules for HTML elements that would go in a form and just by way of having them in your HTML the stylesheet should apply to them.  Are you having a different experience?

Comment: Hi Tony, I am having a different experience, for instance if I add a button using custom code it does not look the same as if I created a button using the theme builder. 

I am essentially going to code a page contain all the forms and php needed for the calculations.

Comment: CSS in a child theme can style Divi components, just make sure you haven't added custom styling in Divi as these are usually applied as inline styles. https://divi.space/tutorials/5-ways-to-add-css-to-divi/

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, will look into that.